# WebException with SecureChannelFailure in high latency situation

Tags: c#, .net, rest, ssl, https

I have a .NET 3.5 application, client of some REST services, and deployed in networks having high latencies (ping time > 300 ms).

In that situation, I regularly have SSL handshake failures : 
`SecureChannelFailure ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`
I looked into System.Net diagnostic traces to know where it fails, but as of now I can't find any precise information.

I made a small test with a cygmin+openssl client, and SSL handshake problems appear with much higher latencies (800 to 1000 ms).

I would like to know if there are some parameters I can tweak in windows/.NET/SSL stack to better tolerate network latencies during SSL handshake.

Any idea ?